# outlook 2010 non-delivery reports chinese/junk characters

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, amazon-web-services, exchange-2013

I have an Exchange 2013 mailbox that receives bounce reports (non-delivery reports) auto generated by our Amazon SES account. The reports come in as english HTML messages with content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" in the meta when I view the message source. The reports appear correctly in the message pane of Outlook 2010, but when I attempt to forward one of them the editor switches to rich-text and the body text becomes chinese/junk characters but the subject line remains as expected.

If I try to forward a regular message sent to the same mailbox (anything other than a non-delivery report) it works as expected. I logged into the mailbox using OWA, the web interface for exchange, and non-delivery report messages have the same behavior of turning to junk/chinese characters when forwarded. What is going on?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, and is best resolved by upgrading to Office 2013, and installing the following hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2985509